# How to use the result of a built-in SQL function twice in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm developing against MS SQL Server 2008.

I'm working with a SQL query written by another developer with a case statement that looks like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN substring(A,4,3) is null THEN '????'
    WHEN substring(A,4,3) in ('000','010','018') THEN '100L'
    WHEN substring(A,4,3) = '123' AND substring(A,8,3) = 'abc' THEN 'FOO'
END
```

My thought here is that it is redundant to use `substring(A,4,3)` and there ought to be some way to avoid it.

How can I rewrite this clause calling `substring(A,4,3)` only once?

Comment: That's not a valid case statement, the third `WHEN` has no corresponding `THEN`.

Comment: @RedFilter, I fixed that!  I redacted some sensitive information from the query and accidently made it invalid.

Comment: There's no performance difference. The engine is not actually performing that 3 times. The optimizer will only have to perform that once. There's no use optimizing this statement. Any alternative to this will only make your code less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select case 
        when substr1 is null
            then '????'
        when substr1 in ('000', '010', '018')
            then '100L'
        when substr1 = '123'
            and substring(A, 8, 3) = 'abc'
            then 'xxx'
        end
from (
    select substring(A, 4, 3) as substr1 from MyTable
    ) a
```

Comment: I was about to post the exact same thing, then got to wondering whether the end result would be the same once the sql optimizer processed the query.

Comment: The larger query that contains this CASE statement is already in a subquery, so I was hoping to avoid writing a subquery.  I was also wondering if this repetition might be optimized, as you suppose.

Comment: You can use subqueries, cte or temp tables if you're worried about having to perform this again but optimizing this piece will not have any performance impact.